# Menú anidado en plantilla Laravel para tener mismo menú en varias plantillas Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

¿Cómo se puede anidar un mismo menú en varias plantillas Blade?
Pongo un ejemplo de un menú (simplificado) y dos plantillas donde insertarles el mismo menú:

Ejemplo:

**menu.blade.php**

```
<menu>
  <a href="#">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#">Foro</a>
  <a href="#">Contactar</a>
</menu>
```

plantilla1.blade.php

```
<html>...
 <head><title>Página1</title></head>
 <body>
 @include('menu')
 @yield("contenido1")
 </body>
</html>
```

plantilla2.blade.php

```
<html>...
 <head><title>Página2</title></head>
 <body>
 @include('menu')
 @yield("contenido1")
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto, funciona bien.
he debido de poner algo incorrecto, y al corregir, funciona perfecto al igual que el ejemplo en mi pregunta.